# How to change d3js treemap rect fill color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I'm testing a d3js treemap from a blog. Please see the live [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/qenucayo/5/watch?html,css,js,output).

I want to control the filling color of each rect for each small area. I don't know where can I control the color of rect. I found the following part is setting the color.

```
 childEnterTransition.append("rect")
            .classed("background", true)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.parent.name);
            });
```

I try to remove the fill or change the color, the filling color is not working. For example I want to change all rect fill color to FFF, it is not working at all.

```
 childEnterTransition.append("rect")
            .classed("background", true)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return '#FFF';
            });
```

Comment: Your JSBin example isn't working for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, please see the original blog at http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2012/12/16/d3-treemap-with-title-headers/

Comment: Well it looks to me like your code is correct.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Do you know how to change the color of the rect fill color?

Comment: Exactly like you're doing it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, thanks! Could you provide a working jsbin example. I tried many times but can not change the fill color.

Comment: See e.g. http://jsbin.com/aGIvOnEH/16/edit

Comment: Thanks! I can make your example change color. But still can not make mine works. It is very wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the fill colour <del>twice</del> *three times* -- once in the "enter" chain for new elements, and then again in the "update" chain for all elements, and then a third time during the zoom transition.  If you're only changing one of those pieces of code, the others may be replacing your setting.

Enter code (from your [bl.ocks page](http://bl.ocks.org/billdwhite/4325239)):

```
    childEnterTransition.append("rect")
        .classed("background", true)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.parent.name); //change this
        });
```

Update code: *You can probably delete the entire update chain and just use the zoom function to update the values to the current zoom.*

```
    childUpdateTransition.select("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return Math.max(0.01, d.dx);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return d.dy;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.parent.name); //change this
        });
```

Zoom code:

```
    zoomTransition.select("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return Math.max(0.01, (kx * d.dx));
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return d.children ? headerHeight : Math.max(0.01, (ky * d.dy));
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.children ? headerColor : color(d.parent.name); //change this
        });
```

Also, just to nitpick:  Your "enter" selection (`childEnterTransition`) isn't actually a transition.  If it was, there would be no point to setting the colour there and then re-setting it in update, because the update transition would just cancel the earlier transition.  But because it *isn't* a transition, setting the colour there creates a starting value for the entering elements before you transition *all* the elements to the current value.

Comment: thanks! Please see this jsbin http://jsbin.com/qenucayo/28/watch . I changed both fill color, it is still not working. I don't know where the color come from.

Comment: Urgh.  There's a *third* place where the colour is being set, in the zoom transition, and that seems to be the one actually being used.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Any tutorials for d3.js? I just start to learn it from yesterday?

Comment: There's a long list of [tutorials on the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials); the first few in the list are good introductions.  For a more comprehensive overview for beginners, I would recommend [Scott Murray](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/) or [Malcolm Maclean](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read)'s books; both are available to read for free online.